# Gherkin format to cover repeatable scenarios

Tags: gherkin

I have the following Gherkin lines in a feature file

```
Feature: Vessel - x memo

    Background:
        Given that logged in user is on home page
            
    @debug
    Scenario Outline:  Verify something for all links in a table
        When clicking on the 'x' link
        Then a new pop up should be displayed with 'x' name as title
        And a pop body should contain the data for 'x'
```

The tricky part is, I had to validate all the 'n' number of links (which is dynamic) in a page/table by performing the above steps again and again. but not sure, how I can come up with a gherkin format that covers the same. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this approach you can use the same step for multiple inputs and outputs.

```
Scenario Outline:  Verify something for all links in a table
        When clicking on the "<link>"
        Then a new pop up should be displayed with "<link>" name as title
        And a pop body should contain the data for "<link>"
Examples:
|   link   |
|firstlink |
|secondlink|
|thirdlink |
```

```
When('clicking on the {string}', async (link: string) => {
       //step def
});
```